# Clicking on a column in DataGrid after Binding

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have the following DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentX}" ColumnWidth="*" ItemsSource="{Binding Model.Xlist, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="GO">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Width="30" Height="30" Source="../Resources/xx.ico" MouseDown="Image_MouseDown">
                        </Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

When I click on a row the click occurs before binding to SelectedItem, I want it to be in the opposite way(first the binding and then the event of the click),

it is possible to do this?

Comment: Are you sure `Selecteditem` get ever binded to `CurrentX`?

Comment: Yes, because when I change the selection it comes to the Property Set

Comment: And it changes but only After clicking, I need this to happen before because what is happening on clicking associated with the current row

Comment: Use `SelectionChanged` event, it should work with that

Comment: But I do not triggering the event when you change a selection, only when click the image that is in a particular column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem. Use `MouseUp` event:

```
<my:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="18" CanUserResize="False">
    <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Width="16" Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp">
                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.ShowErrorMessageCommand}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```